# Updating MS Access Database Through DataGridView

Tags: c#

hi guys I'm trying to save data to database through datagridview with a button but I get the following error every time I run the application and here's my code:

```
        DataTable Table = new DataTable(); 
        BindingSource bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();
 string connetionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:/Database/Database.accdb;";
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM IAE;";
        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connetionString);
        OleDbDataAdapter dataadapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connection);
        OleDbCommandBuilder cb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(dataadapter);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        connection.Open();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["IAE"];
        dataadapter.Update((DataTable)bindingSource1.DataSource);
        connection.Close();
```

the error : Value Cannot be null. Parameter name: dataTable

need your help and thanks

Answer (score 0):

Reason of error is your bindingSource1.DataSource property is NULL. Your are not assigning any DATASOURCE to your bindingsource class